# Eclipse suspend a specific thread while letting others run

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, debugging

Is there a way for the debugger to pause a specific thread while letting the other ones run? I want to verify some locks I have are working properly and Im not sure how to induce certain conditions. Note that all the threads run through the same code, so any changes to the code will affect *all* threads, where as I only want to stop *one* thread.

Comment: Did you try `Suspend` on the specific thread . I'm not sure it will let other threads to execute !!!

Comment: The threads finish in a split second, how am I suppose to suspend them?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at testing frameworks like [MultithreadedTC](http://www.cs.umd.edu/projects/PL/multithreadedtc/) - which lets you programmatically control flow through the different threads during the test so you can cause race conditions and timeouts during testing.

Comment: Bit more heavy weight than I was looking for. I was hoping there was just a button I could press.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a convenient point in your code to set a breakpoint for that single thread, you can change the [`Suspend Policy`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-suspendpolicy_option.htm) of that breakpoint in its properties to only stop the current thread instead of the whole VM.

Comment: But all my threads run through the same code. How do I get it to only suspend *one* thread?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method to do a sleep in the thread. Then you can call that method with junit or a simple POJO.

Comment: Same problem as the other answer - if I put a `sleep()` in there then *all* the threads will sleep, where as I just want *one* thread to sleep, or suspend, or in any other way not run to completion until I tell it to.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort of fix my own problem by basically putting the following code in the thread code -

```
if(Thread.currentThread.getName()="thread1"){
    Thread.currentThread.sleep(5000);
}
```

This way only thread 1 sleeps. It worked well enough that I saw my locks working, but this isnt really a good solution I feel. Perhaps someone can make something better?